# Make "name" not appear on url using a <select>

Tags: html, html-select

I'm writing a simple form, but I've encountered a problem. The form must generate an url like this

`https://website.com/properties/hotelvinadelmar?locale=es&check_in_date=22-03-2019&check_out_date=25-03-2019&number_adults=4&number_children=9`

The part after /properties/ (in this case, "hotelvinadelmar") is a code for an especific hotel, while the rest is the information the customer provide to check if there's availability. 
I wrote this form:

```
Sucursal: <br>
<select name="test" id="id" required>       
        <option value="hotelvinadelmar?locale=es">Viña del Mar</option>
        <option value="hotelsantiago1?locale=es">Nueva Providencia</option>
        <option value="hotelsantiago2?locale=es">Providencia</option></select> 
    <br><br>
</select>
```

this almost work, but generates an url like this 
 `(...)/properties/?test=hotelvinadelmar?locale=es&number_adults=1(...)`

Which is creating an url structured like this 
`[form action (the url I entered)][Option Name][selected Option Value]`

But the thing must be like this 
`[form action (the url I entered)][selected Option Value]`

How can this be achieved? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct behavior because the submitted form data  `test=hotelvinadelmar` will be added after the URL 
 `(...)/properties/`, in order the achieve the desired result you can try to add `action` attribute to your form as `<form action="/hotel">` and change the select as:

```
<select name="hotelname" required>       
        <option value="hotelvinadelmar">Viña del Mar</option>
        <option value="hotelsantiago1">Nueva Providencia</option>
        <option value="hotelsantiago2">Providencia</option></select> 
    <br><br>
</select>
```

the generated link will be: `(...)/properties/hotel?name=hotelvinadelmar(...)`

or you can use a javascript function with `onSubmit` event, for example:

```
<script>
function submitForm(){
    var hotelName = document.getElementById('hotelName').value;
    var param1Value = document.getElementById('id').value;
    switch(hotelName) {
        case 'hotelvinadelmar':
           window.location.href = '/hotelvinadelmar?param1=' + param1Value + '&param2=' + (...);
           break;
        case 'hotelsantiago1':
           window.location.href = '/hotelsantiago1?param1=' + param1Value;
           break;

    }
    // stop submit
    return false;
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="submitForm()" method="get">
    <select id="hotelName" required>       
        <option value="hotelvinadelmar">Viña del Mar</option>
        <option value="hotelsantiago1">Nueva Providencia</option>
        <option value="hotelsantiago2">Providencia</option></select> 
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
However, the first option won't work, because I need the hotel value to be clean after the `properties/` part.

And about the second option.. I'm sorry, but I don't know how to make it work, I'm pretty new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the submission event and update the form `action` attribute to append the hotel name to the submission path:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
  let ff = evt.target;      
  ff.action = "/properties/" + ff.hotelname.options[ff.hotelname.selectedIndex].value;
});
```

You'll need remove the `locale` property from your `select` input. Simply add a `hidden` form element (or selectable option) to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="es">
```

An example url:

```
https://website.com/properties/hotelvinadelmar?locale=es&hotelname=hotelvinadelmar&val1=one&val2=two
```

Here's a demonstration how the form `action` attribute can be updated:

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); // demonstration only
  let ff = evt.target;
  
  ff.action = "/properties/" + ff.hotelname.options[ff.hotelname.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(ff.action); // demonstration only
  return false; // demonstration only
});
```

```html
<form action="/properties/" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="es">
  Sucursal:
  <select name="hotelname" id="id" required>
    <option value="hotelvinadelmar">Viña del Mar</option>
    <option value="hotelsantiago1">Nueva Providencia</option>
    <option value="hotelsantiago2">Providencia</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="val1" value="one">
  <input type="hidden" name="val2" value="two">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```